# data-history-node-id after updating Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, updates, drupal-8

I've updated an older version of Drupal 8 to Drupal 8.3.1 on a localhost. And since then, the body content doesn't appear. Instead, there is only an HTML tag like this:

```
<data-history-node-id="8" data-quickedit-entity-id="node/8" class="contextual-region ds-1col clearfix">
```

It is the same on every node of the site. This kind of line appear like this in the source code. Editing the node, the normal text is editable in the form.

I can imagine it has something to do with quickedit!?!

But how can I fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem should certainly come from display suite module.
If you are using Drupal 8.3, then you have to upload display suite to his 8.3 version.

Have a look on ds description :
https://www.drupal.org/project/ds